# How can I render two object in div?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have 2 objects with data and I need to restruct the rendering in html.

This is what I get:

[image]

but this is what I need to obtain:

[image: second]

Black box is the `*ngFor` of `articles` object, respectively red one is `*ngFor` of `adsContainer` object

```
<div *ngFor="let article of articles; let i = index;">

<mat-card class="card">
  <div>
    <a class="title">
      {{article.title}}
    </a>
    <a>
      <p>{{article.content}}</p>
    </a>
  </div>

</mat-card>

<div class="container" *ngIf="(i % 7) === 6">
  <div *ngFor="let data of adsContainer">
    <div>
      <h1>{{data.value}}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

```
  public adsContainer: any = [
    { id: '1', value: 'text value here' },
    { id: '2', value: 'text value here' },
    { id: '3', value: 'text value here' }
  ]
```

```
  public articles: any = [
    { id: '1', title: 'title value here', content: 'content here' },
    { id: '2', title: 'title value here', content: 'content here' },
    { id: '3', title: 'title value here', content: 'content here' },
    ........
    { id: '20', title: 'title value here', content: 'content here' },
  ]
```

Comment: Could you at least post your object code? And explain a bit more about what your are trying to do?

Comment: Can you check the question ?

Comment: Thank you for sharing. But still could not figure out what you are trying to do. This images you have posted do not explain enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use directly the array , also when you call
**adsContainer[(parseInt(i / 6)-1)% adsContainer.length**, it will always restart the index:

```
<div *ngFor="let article of articles; let i = index;">
    
  <mat-card class="card">
    <div>
      <a class="title">
        {{article.title}}
      </a>
      <a>
        <p>{{article.content}}</p>
      </a>
    </div> 
  
  </mat-card>
  
  <div class="container" *ngIf="(i % 7) === 6">
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>{{adsContainer[(parseInt(i / 6)-1)%adsContainer.length].value}}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you add your ads containers in a loop

```xml
<div class="container" *ngIf="(i % 7) === 6">
  <!-- this loop here -->
  <div *ngFor="let data of adsContainer">
    <div>
      <h1>{{data.value}}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

what you want is to add only one ad container at a time, in order to do that, you have to rmove the loop

In order to have the three ads show, you'll have to do some math to get the ad index from the article index

something like this :

```xml
<div class="container" *ngIf="(i % 7) === 6">
  <div>
    <h1>{{adsContainer[mathFloor(i / 7)].value}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

note that `Math` is not available in angular templates, you'll have to redefine floor as a component method

```js
function mathFloor(val) {return Math.floor(val)}
```